# G++ Compiler Error, When Trying To Include Header Only Library

Tags: c++, linker-errors, asio

I'm trying to compile a c++ code on windows using asio library, which is a header only library, and getting a massive compiler error. I don't get it, only including the directory should work. How can I solve this, and why is this happening?

`g++ main.cpp -o main -I ./asio-1.20.0/include`

It's many lines of prompt, doesn't even fit the screen, which I can't dump here but at the start it gives an error saying:

`You must add -D_USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.`

And before that there are couple of warnings, first one being:

`Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.`

These come from `./asio-1.20.0/include/asio/detail/config.hpp`, I probably need to link against some windows library.

Comment: Just because a library is header-only does not necessarily means that you do not need to link with anything else. The library might have dependencies that you need to link with. That is likely the case here. I haven't used asio in particular for more help, but usually the library documentation specifies which dependencies you need to link with.

Comment: ***getting a massive linker error*** If you add the error as text maybe someone can help you with the dependencies.

Comment: *You must add -D_USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options.* -- Did you do this?

Comment: Yep,  did it. Again massive dump of errors.

Comment: You say "massive dump of errors".  Are any of them related to calls to Winsock that cannot be found?  If you had used Visual C++, `ws2_32.lib` is required to build a program using Winsock.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt)

Comment: It turns out that asio supports mingw or cygwin on windows, which I didn't had. I had gcc compilers on top of msys, I've downloaded gcc from mingw now it works. Thanks everyone for helping

Comment: ***I had gcc compilers on top of msys*** Doesn't that a provide a newer version of mingw? Also msys2 has asio in the package management: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-asio?repo=mingw64](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-asio?repo=mingw64)

Comment: Well, don't know about that. Uninstalled msys2 and installed mingw, same makefile, built without any problem.